# Access Hive Data Using Python

Tags: python, hive

I have some data in HDFS,i need to access that data using python,can anyone tell me how data is accessed from hive using python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You can use hive library for access hive from python,for that you want to import hive Class
from hive import ThriftHive*

Below the  Example

```
import sys

from hive import ThriftHive
from hive.ttypes import HiveServerException

from thrift import Thrift
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol

try:
  transport = TSocket.TSocket('localhost', 10000)
  transport = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(transport)
  protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
  client = ThriftHive.Client(protocol)
  transport.open()
  client.execute("CREATE TABLE r(a STRING, b INT, c DOUBLE)")
  client.execute("LOAD TABLE LOCAL INPATH '/path' INTO TABLE r")
  client.execute("SELECT * FROM r")
  while (1):
    row = client.fetchOne()
    if (row == None):
       break
    print row

  client.execute("SELECT * FROM r")
  print client.fetchAll()
  transport.close()
except Thrift.TException, tx:
  print '%s' % (tx.message)
```

Comment: plz tell me how to get hive library?

Comment: you can get that library from $HIVE_HOME/lib/py/* copy that content inside the py folder and past into python library

Comment: @Sreejith I have no problem importing those python libraries, however, the code hangs after executing hive command. And it turned out to be a general problem. Were your code connecting to Hiveserver1 or Hiveserver2? https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/lCSuh6vLmHM

Answer (score 12):

To install you'll need these libraries:

```
pip install sasl
pip install thrift
pip install thrift-sasl
pip install PyHive
```

If you're on Linux, you may need to install SASL separately before running the above.  Install the package `libsasl2-dev` using `apt-get` or `yum` or whatever package manager. For Windows there are some options [on GNU.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/manual/html_node/Installing-under-Windows.html). On a Mac SASL should be available if you've installed xcode developer tools (`xcode-select --install`)

After installation, you can execute a hive query like this:

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="YOUR_HIVE_HOST", port=PORT, username="YOU")
```

Now that you have the hive connection, you have options how to use it.  You can just straight-up query:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT cool_stuff FROM hive_table")
for result in cursor.fetchall():
  use_result(result)
```

...or to use the connection to make a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT cool_stuff FROM hive_table", conn)
```

Comment: "Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()" - under Windows 2008 R2, python 3.6. How solve this problem?

Comment: this is thrift issue, I was facing the same issue, on Linux environment, it works fine.

Comment: Confirming the windows issue and that it does work on Linux.  I use Windows 10 for development (PyCharm).  I could not "pip install pyhive[hive]" there; the dependencies fail.  But if you just "pip install pyhive" (or whatever, using PyCharm's package manager), then you can develop against it.  When I import PyHive I wrap it in a if os.name != "nt": statement so it is skipped on Windows.  Everything installs and works fine on Linux though (Centos 7).

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution if you're on Windows uses `pyodbc`:

```
  import pyodbc
  import pandas as pd

  # connect odbc to data source name
  conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=<your_dsn>", autocommit=True)

  # read data into dataframe
  hive_df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM <table_name>", conn)
```

As long as you have an ODBC driver and a DSN, that's all you need.

Comment: It's not that simple on Linux   : -/

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter good point- I'll add a note specifying that my solution is for Windows.

Comment: It's _doable_ on Linux, just not trivial (check that the installed version of `unixODBC` is recent enough, check that your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` taps its libraries, install the appropriate ODBC driver, reference that driver in `odbcinst.ini`, define a DSN in `odbc.ini`, troubleshoot)