# Access Hive (Hiveserver2) Using Python

Tags: python, hive, thrift, hue

My whole goal is to manipulate Hive like everyone manipulate sqldb using MySQLdb in Python.

- hue shell: I have no problem querying Hive table in hue shell, however, the hue shell is somehow a wrapper built on python with a lot of configurations added comparing with simple python. For example, tons of `sys.path` and `os.environ` has been added and even if I copied exactly the same path and environment variable  when I open Python, it still will not work due to some error `AttributeError: 'ConfigSection' object has no attribute 'HUE_PRINCIPAL'`.
- The [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722372/access-hive-data-using-python) works only for hiveserver1, I think. And the conversation from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/lCSuh6vLmHM) keeps talking about get client generated by thrift. I have zero experience working with thrift and I am wondering am I on the wrong way, before diving into thrift.

Any help would be appreicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I use this package to do what I want.

[pyhs2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyhs2/0.2)

Answer (score 0):

If using the [Hue shell](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/49882746559/tutorial-executing-hive-or-impala-queries-with-python) Hue comes as dependency. If you want to streamline it you would need to isolate the [Thrift implentation](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server) lib and [generated Python](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/beeswax/gen-py) from the [HiveServer2 Thrift interface](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/apps/beeswax/thrift/TCLIService.thrift).