# pyhive, sqlalchemy can not connect to hadoop sandbox

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, sqlalchemy, pyhive

I have installed,

```
pip install thrift
pip install PyHive
pip install thrift-sasl
```

and 
since `pip install sasl` failed I downloaded [sasl‑0.2.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#sasl) file and installed it in my Windows 8.1 PC.

Then I wrote this code,

```
from pyhive import hive
cursor = hive.connect('192.168.1.232', port=10000, auth='NONE')
cursor.execute('SELECT * from sample_07 LIMIT 5',async=True)
print cursor.fetchall()
```

this gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DigInEngine/scripts/UserManagementService/fd.py", line 37, in <module>
    cursor = hive.connect('192.168.1.232', port=10000, auth = 'NONE')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 63, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyhive\hive.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._transport.open()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\thrift_sasl\__init__.py", line 72, in open
    message=("Could not start SASL: %s" % self.sasl.getError()))
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2
```

and this code gives,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('hive://192.168.1.232:10000/default')
try:
    connection = engine.connect()
except Exception, err:
    print err
result = connection.execute('select * from sample_07;')
engine.dispose()
```

this error,

> Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no
>   mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2

I have downloaded Hortonworks sandbox from [here](http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox) and use it in a separate server.

**NOTE:** I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722372/access-hive-data-using-python) as well but the accepted answer is not working for me, because importing ThriftHive from hive gives Import error although I have pip installed hive. So I decided to use pyhive or sqlalchemy

How can I connect to hive and execute a query easily?

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to build SASL on Windows, but your mileage may vary: A lot of this depends on your particular system's paths and available libraries.

Please also note that these instructions are specific to Python 2.7 (which I see you are using from the paths in your question).

The high-level overview is that you're installing this project:  https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl.  In order to do that, you have to use the legacy C++ compiler that was used to build Python 2.7.  There are a couple of other steps to getting this to work.

**Pre-build Steps:**

1. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=44266).  Use the default installation paths - take note of where it got installed for the next 2 steps (2 options are included in the list below)
2. Copy [this file](http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/msp430-libc/ci/master/tree/include/stdint.h?format=raw) to whichever of the include locations is appropriate for your install
3. Make a unistd.h file from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341817/is-there-a-replacement-for-unistd-h-for-windows-visual-c) in the same include directory

**Build steps:**

4. `git clone https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl`
5. Open the "VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" that's installed with the Compiler from step 1
6. Change directory to the directory created by step 4, then the `lib` sub-directory
7. `nmake /f ntmakefile STATIC=no prefix=C:\sasl64`
8. `nmake /f ntmakefile prefix=C:\sasl64 STATIC=no install` *see note below*
9. `copy /B C:\sasl64\lib\libsasl.lib /B C:\sasl64\lib\sasl2.lib`
10. `pip install thrift_sasl --global-option=build_ext \
                --global-option=-IC:\\sasl64\\include \
                --global-option=-LC:\\sasl64\\lib`

**'Include' locations:**

- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include\stdint.h"
- "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include"

Here's a reference to these same steps, with some additional annotations and explanations:  http://java2developer.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/making-impala-connection-from-python-on.html.

*Note*
The referenced instructions also executed step (8) in the `include` and `win32\include` sub-directories, you may have to do that as well.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer and your time. I'll try this and accept the answer if works. :)

Comment: But the error says Could not start SASL. It doesnot say the absence of it.. Anyway I'll try what you said

Comment: Any advice for python 3?

Answer (score 1):

While using pyhive no authentication can be passed as `auth="NOSASL"`, instead of `"None"`, so your code should look like this:

```
from pyhive import hive
cursor = hive.connect('192.168.1.232', port=10000, auth='NOSASL')
cursor.execute('SELECT * from sample_07 LIMIT 5',async=True)
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I think this is not an authentication issue, I changed to linux which makes the developers lives easy